# Uprobe: unable to get (in some cases) the value of argument given to fopen

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf

I'm actually playing with BPFTrace and Python BCC to discover the fascinating world of eBPF.

As my first POC for Uprobes, I wanted to print to stdout all the file opened by **fopen** calls. So, I wrote the following BPFTrace script:

```
BEGIN
{
    printf("Hit Ctrl-C to end.\n");
}

uprobe:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:fopen
{
    printf("File opened: %s\n", str(arg0));
}
```

To test it, I wrote this little C language POC:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    char *filename = "/etc/issue";
    FILE *fd = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fd == NULL){
        return -1;
    }

    fclose(fd);
    return 0;

}
```

When I run my bpftrace script I get this output:

```
sudo bpftrace ./trace.bt
Attaching 2 probes...
Hit Ctrl-C to end.

File opened:
```

It seems like the BPF program is not able to retrieve the filename.

When I modify the C POC like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    char filename[] = "/etc/issue";
    FILE *fd = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fd == NULL){
        return -1;
    }

    fclose(fd);
    return 0;

}
```

The resulting BPF trace is:

```
sudo bpftrace ./trace.bt                                                                                    
Attaching 2 probes...
Hit Ctrl-C to end.
File opened: /etc/issue
```

The only difference I notice there is that in the first case, the "/etc/issue" string is stored in .rodata section because of the difference in the variable declaration : **char filename[]** instead of **char *filename**.

I am a little bit confused, I do not understand why it makes a difference for Uprobes.

The C code was compiled using: `gcc -o test testing.c`.

I am using the following environment :

Kali Linux with Kernel *Linux kali 6.0.0-kali3-amd64* and bpftrace v0.16.0

**EDIT:** Well, it appears to be something not really (only?) related to read-only content.

Using this program as a test:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   
    FILE *fds[5];

    fds[0] = fopen("/etc/issue", "r");
    fds[1] = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r");
    fds[2] = fopen("/etc/nanorc", "r");
    fds[3] = fopen("/etc/netconfig", "r");
    fds[4] = fopen("/etc/pam.conf", "r");

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        if(fds[i] != NULL){
            fclose(fds[i]);
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following trace:

```
sudo bpftrace ./trace.bt                                                                                      
Attaching 2 probes...
Hit Ctrl-C to end.
File opened: 
File opened: /etc/passwd
File opened: /etc/nanorc
File opened: /etc/netconfig
File opened: /etc/pam.conf
```

The trace never catches the first arg from the first call to **fopen**. At this time, I have no idea what is going on and how to go deeper in finding the bug root.